# The getter 'onAuthStateChanged' isn't defined for the type 'FirebaseAuth'

Tags: flutter

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o24Hz.jpg)

```
UserProvider.initialize() : _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance {
    _auth.onAuthStateChanged.listen(_onStateChanged);
  }
```

I'm Getting an error:
The getter 'onAuthStateChanged' isn't defined for the type 'FirebaseAuth'.  Try importing the library that defines 'onAuthStateChanged', correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'onAuthStateChanged'.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue.

Try this instead: `authStateChanges()`.